# Fullcalendar - move other events when i drop the new

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, fullcalendar

- I have event(1) at 8-12 a.m.
- The new event(2) I want to put at 10-11 a.m.
- The event(1) is moved and sliced, and it is between 8-10 and 11-13.

The data I store in MySql.

Events can't overlap. There can be only one event at a given time.

I used `eventOverlap`. I now have a problem with moving / slicing events.

Is there a way to move and slice events when I drop the new one on them?

Comment: Please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: yes I think so. the overlap event (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventOverlap/) should give you the details of the event already on the calendar. So you just need to change that into two events and set the times appropriately. Then save to the DB, presumably.